# java 7, select and update on a table that depend on the dbms

Tags: java, sql

Sorry for my bad english. I have to read and update one table using java 7 (I'm developing an application desktop and I'm new with java 7). My problem is that I have to be able to access multiple-DBMSs and the name of the table and its attributes could be slightly different depending on the dbms.
Also, to cup it all, the user and password are encrypted with a proprietary algorithm.
To sum up, I need a way to:
- connect to a dbms or another (in execution time)
- perform a select and update on a table that could be different depending on the dbms (only one table).
- connect using a user and password dencrypted in execution time.

What should I use? an orm? jpa? It must be simple, because is only one table and that's all.

It could be a bad idea to use a properties file where to set the sql sentences (select and update), user encrypted, password encryption and connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use JPA, at least not *simply*, since the table names differ. In any case, using JPA for a database with a single table seems like overkill.

The problem does not sound that complex to me though. Just load up different table name and columns names (if they differ too) depending on the type of database you are connecting to, and use these details to build up plain old JDBC preparedStatements to do the database select / insert / update / delete.

The username and password being encrypted will not be a problem at all, no matter which DBMS you are connecting to, as long as you encrypt the password in the same way as the database and then compare to the already encrypted password on the database, you should be fine.